# how to decode json array in php?

Tags: php

lets say I have an json array like

```
{
    [
       {"id" : 1, "src" : src1, "name" : name1},
       {"id" : 2, "src" : src2, "name" : name2},
       {"id" : 3, "src" : src3, "name" : name3},
       {"id" : 4, "src" : src4, "name" : name4}
    ]
}
```

how should I decode this json array in php??

```
$project_info_json = $_POST['project_info_json'];

if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $project_info_json =  stripslashes($_POST['project_info_json']);
}else {
    $project_info_json = $_POST['project_info_json'];
}
$project_info_array = json_decode($project_info_json, true);
```

I already tried json_decode method but it seems like $project_info_array has 0 element count. can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: That isn't valid JSON or a valid object literal. I think you've mixed up your square and curly brackets

Comment: Still not valid. Lose the outer `{}`

Comment: @Lee Have you created this json input... If so, first validate it using http://jsonlint.com/ and find what's the error. Then just use json_decode() function. Php will do it for you..

Answer (score 0):

i Think this is not valid JSON

JSON should be like

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "src": "src1",
        "name": "name1"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "src": "src2",
        "name": "name2"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "src": "src3",
        "name": "name3"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "src": "src4",
        "name": "name4"
    }
]
```

Validate Your JSON @ http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score -1):

Your outer object in json does not have a key where the internal list is stored in.

Also, your strings in json should be quoted.
`src1`, `name1` are unquoted.